# Limit the use of my Apple ID on my kid's iPod Touch

Tags: data-synchronization, ipod, apple-id

I've had an iPod Touch (4G) for a couple years. Now I have an iPhone 5, so I want to remove all "my" apps/profile info from my iPod Touch and set it up for my children to use.

Right now, both devices use my apple ID, and share some (but not all) applications (mostly free ones). But that means, for instance, when I get an iOS message, it is going to both devices, which I don't want. Both devices sync to my laptop. I have music that I'd like to be able to keep on both devices.

What's the best set-up? Is my best scenario to create a new Apple ID for my kids' use, and reset my old iPod Touch and start over with the new ID? (is there any way to keep the set-up, like if I back-up and then restore? Or should I continue using the same ID for both devices? I'm worried about getting apps/profile info mixed up and accidentally downloading ones I don't want the kids to have to the iPod (e.g., I don't want them to be able to send messages to my contact list, which is mostly business!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all depends on where you want to go with the Apple IDs after this. Even if you want the kids to all have their own Apple IDs in the future, because it is just one device, it probably is a good idea to just stick with one Apple ID.

In this case, I would recommend using **your** Apple ID for purchasing content. This way, any time apps are purchased, they stay with your account, instead of having a third account to try to remember for buying apps and such - after the kids get their own devices and Apple IDs. [Parental Restrictions on iOS devices](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4213) have a nice amount of control over disabling features and other things such as setting age limits on purchasing content, or disabling the App and iTunes stores altogether.

To remove your personal information:

1. Open Settings.app and scroll and tap on Mail, Contacts, Calendars.
2. Delete any of your mail accounts (if applicable) that you don't want your kids to access *including* the first one - "iCloud".

   1. When you do get to iCloud, scroll down to the bottom on that one and tap delete. Don't worry, it's only removing the account and information from your device - not the account itself.
3. Go back to the main Settings.app menu and scroll down to Messages. Scroll to "Send & Receive at". Tap the Apple ID at the top and Sign Out".
4. Go to "Facetime" and make sure you are signed out of your Apple ID.
5. To make sure your old iPod doesn't download any new content that you download onto your new iPod, go to Settings.app > iTunes & App Stores and disable "Automatic Downloads".

   1. After this go to Parental Restrictions and see if there is an option to disable changing that Automatic Download setting (I'm not sure on that one).
   2. The *for sure* method, in addition to disabling Automatic Downloads is to disable iBooks, iTunes, and App store. The device will *not* download content when these stores are disabled.

Now, after that you could set up an Apple ID for Facetime, Messages, and iCloud, if you wanted. You would then use that to just log in those places and not the app store.

Comment: If I do this, won't all the apps I get for my iPhone install onto my iPod when I sync?

Comment: @Albie, You bring up a good point. I added step #5 to my answer. It would probably be good to have the stores disabled anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want your children to have access to your Address Book (that syncs using iCloud), you should use a new Apple ID. This means you have to turn off and change the current iCloud settings in the iPod Touch.

Since you want to keep the apps you already installed (using your iCloud), you shouldn't  restore the iPod Touch to its original (factory) state as that will delete those apps.

I'll recommend backing up (whether via iCloud or to your Mac) using iTunes just in case you want to use the iPod Touch again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your Apple ID to the App Store to share purchases and music but create a new ID to be used for iMessage, device backup, etc. on the second device.

**Apple Knowledgebase:** [***Using your Apple ID for Apple services***](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4895)